# How shall i get my friends of friends using mysql and PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Currently I am in need to find the friends of friends in my application using PHP and MYSQL

For example: Database structure is like this. Table Name: `tbl_friendlist`

```
Ident   mem_id  friend_id
1         2        1
2         1        2
3         1        3
1         4        1
5         1        8
```

How can i achieve this

I am able to get the Friends by

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_friendlist WHERE mem_id = 1.
```

By using this i am able to get my friends list. Now how can i get the **friends of friends**

Comment: 1. column stands for: id is auto increment, mem_id is the current user id and friend_id is id of the friends. 

2. There is no limit for maximum number of friends.

Comment: this is more a logic problem than a technology issue. First, explain to us what do your columns represent. The names are not indicative of what they are used for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would do a subquery as well (my SQL  is really rusty, but the query will look something like this)

```
SELECT * from tbl_friendlist where mem_id in (SELECT friend_id FROM tbl_friendlist WHERE mem_id = 1).
```

Comment: thanks keith, yours code produce the perfect output.. And thanks to all who helps me...

Comment: This works however I chose to upvote a few of the other answers since in large tables, the subquery causes a performance drawback that can be avoided by using a JOIN on itself.

Answer (score 4):

So, breaking into steps -- you want to find all your friends, and then you want to find all of their friends. These are the two parts of your query (and subquery):

This is how you'd get a list of all your friends

```
SELECT friend_id
FROM tbl_friendlist
WHERE f.mem_id = 1
```

And so then you just wrap that in the second part:

```
SELECT f.friend_id
FROM tbl_friendlist f
WHERE f.mem_id IN (
    SELECT f2.friend_id
    FROM tbl_friendlist f2
    WHERE f2.mem_id = 1
)
```

You might also want to add some extra filters in there, eg:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.friend_id
FROM tbl_friendlist f
WHERE f.mem_id IN (
    SELECT f2.friend_id
    FROM tbl_friendlist f2
    WHERE f2.mem_id = 1
) AND f.friend_id <> 1
```

This means you won't get duplicates, and you find yourself in your list of friends' friends.

Comment: You have renamed the tables in subqueries -> "WHERE f2.mem_id = 1"

Comment: I think this leads to wrong output nick.. Because, according to the above table structure if i have the mem_id as 2 then, i need the output as friend_id 2,3,4,8. Because friend_id 1 is my friend. And his friends are obviously 2,3,4,8. So i need 2,3,4,8. But if i have the mem_id as 2 i just get the result freind_id 1. So kindly clear my clarification.. Excuse if anything i mentioned wrong..

Comment: Thanks Lukas. @Fero: that might have been because of the typo which lukas pointed out (changed now). However, from the look of your table, person 1 is not friends with person 4, unless friendships are symmetrical.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to find a way without subqueries you can try to do this by joining the table ON itself.

Idea, untested:

```
SELECT a.mem_id, b.mem_id AS secundaryfriends FROM tbl_friendlist AS a
JOIN tbl_friendlist AS b ON a.friend_id = mem_id;
```

Comment: You should use just "JOIN", because you don't need a NULL if the friend has no friends, and also "b.mem_id AS secundaryfriends" should be "b.friend_id AS secundaryfriends".

Comment: No, it isn't wrong: b.mem_id == a.friend_id, so you are selecting a list of a.mem_id, a.friend_id pairs.

Answer (score 3):

The solution by *nickf* will work well, but I'd personally do this in a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT fof.friend_id
FROM
    tbl_friendlist f
    JOIN tbl_friendlist fof ON fof.mem_id=f.friend_id
WHERE
    f.mem_id = 1 AND fof.friend_id != 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I think something like this may work:

```
SELECT 
   f1.friend_id, group_concat( f2.friend_id ) as f_of_f
FROM 
   tbl_friendlist f1
   LEFT JOIN 
   tbl_friendlist f2 ON ( f1.friend_id = f2.mem_id )
WHERE 
   f1.mem_id = 1
GROUP BY 
   f2.mem_id
```

This will give you the ids of the friends of friends as a comma separate value in f_of_f column.

Answer (score 0):

and the friends of the friends of the friends:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT fof.friend_id
FROM
    tbl_friendlist f
    JOIN tbl_friendlist fof ON fof.mem_id=f.friend_id
    JOIN tbl_friendlist fofof ON fofof.mem_id=fof.friend_id
WHERE
    f.mem_id = 1 AND fof.friend_id != 1;
```

is this correct?